# What type of rotational invariance information can I get from interest points (coordinates) of corners from an image?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, inference, identifiability

Assume that you are using the FAST algoritm for corner/feature detection. You pick an image and run the FAST algorithm.

[image]

**Question:**

All these green dots are actully coordinates in x and y direction. What type of *rotational invariance* information can I get from only knowing the coordinates that are created by the geometical shapes inside the image?

**NOTE**

This is a feature detection algorithm, sometimes one or more coordinates can flicker e.g some green dots disapear and appears few milliseconds after.